# MySQL as a bridge for SQL Server 2008 in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, linux, sql-server-2008, odbc, linktable

In Windows, there is a link table feature in SQL Server (or MS Access). Basically, if I link SQL-Server and MySQL, then when my apps write something in SQL-Server, the MySQL is also updated via ODBC connection.

Basically the flow is: win-apps -> sql-server 2008 -> (via win-odbc) mysql (linux)

Now I want to reverse the process in Linux environment into:

the flow I want is: nix-apps -> mysql (linux) -> (via nix-odbc?) sql-server 2008...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to SQL Server from unixODBC there are a couple of options commercially [Easysoft SQL Server ODBC driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/index.html) or if you prefer an un-supported free version the [Free TDS ODBC driver](http://freetds.schemamania.org/)

Other ODBC drivers are available but may not be compatable with unixODBC.